Calculate Measure Returns Blank
I have a 'Trial Data' table that contains data related to clinical trials. I am attempting to write a measure that calculates the average number of days that it took each trial to become "active," but only for trials that match specific criteria:

Management Status = Active
Time to Activation (Days) >= 0
Lower Outlier Bound < Time to Activation < Upper Outlier Bound

Average TTA (Days) = 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE('Trial Data'[Time to Activation (Days)]),
    'Trial Data'[Management Status]="Active",
    'Trial Data'[Time to Activation (Days)]>=0,
    FILTER('Trial Data',
        AND(
            'Trial Data'[Time to Activation (Days)]>[TTA Outlier Lower Bound],
            'Trial Data'[Time to Activation (Days)]<[TTA Outlier Upper Bound]
        )
    )
)

I've verified in my data that the Time to Activation and the Outlier Lower and Upper Bounds are being calculated correctly. Additionally, all rows where Management Status = Active also meet the rest of the criteria, so they all should be included in the calculation. However, the end result returns blank.
The Standard Deviation, Geometric Mean, and Outlier Lower and Upper Bounds used in the measure are calculated as:
TTA Geometric Mean = GEOMEAN('Trial Data'[Time to Activation (Days)])

TTA Standard Deviation = STDEV.P('Trial Data'[Time to Activation (Days)])

TTA Outlier Lower Bound = [TTA Geometric Mean]-(2*[TTA Standard Deviation])

TTA Outlier Upper Bound = [TTA Geometric Mean]+(2*[TTA Standard Deviation])

I tried rewriting the measure using AVERAGEX instead of CALCULATE, but got the same result.
Any insight as to why this might be happening?

Can you please add the code for the TTA Outlier Lower and Upper Bound measures?

@NickA Sorry about that, I've edited my question to include those measures.

Which visual is this measure being used in? What values are you getting for [TTA Outlier Lower Bound] and [TTA Outlier Upper Bound]?

@SamNseir I'm trying to display [Average TTA (Days)] in a simple Card visual. With my current data, [TTA Outlier Lower Bound] = -13.35 and [TTA Outlier Upper Bound] = 280.14. All values in the [Time to Activation (Days)] calculated column fall within that range, so all should be included in the Average calculation.

I believe your measures are being filtered by the row context of the table, which would result in the data returning blanks. Try these instead:
Average TTA (Days) measure:
Average TTA (Days) = 
CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE('Trial Data'[Time to Activation (Days)]),
    FILTER(ALL('Trial Data'),
    'Trial Data'[Management Status]="Active" &&
    'Trial Data'[Time to Activation (Days)]>=0 &&
    'Trial Data'[Time to Activation (Days)]> [TTA Outlier Lower Bound] &&
    'Trial Data'[Time to Activation (Days)]< [TTA Outlier Upper Bound]
        )

TTA Geometric Mean measure:
TTA Geometric Mean = GEOMEANX(ALL('Trial Data'), [Time to Activation (Days)])

TTA Standard Deviation measure:
TTA Standard Deviation = STDEVX.P(ALL('Trial Data'), [Time to Activation (Days)])

Output:


Thanks, this fixed it! I'll have to read up on row vs. table contexts.
